# Is it possible to somehow have a panel on the right-hand side?

Tags: cinnamon

I recently discovered the Cinnamon desktop. It is an official Linux Mint desktop environment, but I use it on my [fedora-17](/questions/tagged/fedora-17) Linux box. What I miss, however, is the ability to have another panel on the right-hand side where I only store application icons. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure have you tired running [Docky](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki) and moving it to the right of the desktop? Its quite good kind of like the OSX bar. Worth having a look into. Might be able to run that along side cinnamon and have your icon as per requested.

Bill

Comment: Nah, Docky is too wide...

Answer (score -2):

You can right-click on Docky, click settings, and then reduce the icon size to something like 30px, that's what I did.

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. You are not answering the posters question. Also this belongs in the comment section and not in an answer itself. When you get enough reputation points, you will be able to post comments.